# Start Reactive Receiver after Spring Boot main method or after some event

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I am using Reactor Kafka, but cannot solve the following problem.
Is it possible to configure Receiver to start after the application is fully launched, rather than at the moment with the application? Or, for example, that the Receiver is launched after some event?
I couldn't find information about it in the documentation :-(

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how do you launch that receiver at the moment. To be precise there is nothing in Spring Boot which would start consuming from that Kafka receiver automatically. You have to `subscribe()` into the result `Flux` somehow in your code. And that is exactly what you can control in your code. For example, you can catch an `ApplicationReadyEvent` or have an `ApplicationRunner` bean. And call some your service which is going to `subscribe()` to the `Flux` from receiver.

Even Spring for Apache Kafka with its `@KafkaListener` starts consuming only if the application is fully ready. But Reactor Kafka has nothing to do with Spring. You probably just `subscribe()` at some wrong spot.